# Multiple jQuery plugins from a single object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How would one go about creating multiple plugins for jQuery from a single object?

Initially I tried:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = {
    plugin_1: function(options) { alert(this.text( )); },
    plugin_2: function(options) { alert(this.text( )); }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

However, upon doing `$('#element').myPlugin.plugin_1( );` I got: `this.text is not a function`

Comment: `this` refers to `$.fn.myPlugin` and not the selected elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because if you try to namespace things in that way, you mess up the value of `this` within the method calls. (Specifically, `this` will refer to `$.fn.myPlugin` rather than the actual jQuery object.)

`this` in JavaScript is quite different than it is in other languages you may be familiar with, such as C++, Java, or C#. It's defined entirely by *how the function is called*, not where the function is defined. (More on `this`: *[Mythical Methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*.)

The primary way `this` gets set is when you call a function that's a property on an object:

```
foo.bar();
```

That tells JavaScript to look up the property `bar` on the `foo` object and try to call it, setting `this = foo` within the call. So you can see why if you do `$("selector").myPlugin.plugin_1()`, `this` ends up referencing `myPlugin`, not the jQuery object.

You'll have to use a naming convention instead, such as `$.fn.myPlugin_plugin1`, or just keep them separate, but with similar-enough names that people know they're grouped (`$.fn.myPluginFoo`, `$.fn.myPluginBar`).